# Can I mark an answer as correct if the respondent answered in a comment on the original post

Tags: support

On my first ever question, the first response was a comment to the OP, not a separate answer. The commenter actually nailed the issue. There have since been further answers, but I would like to mark the original commenter as the correct answer because s/he was the first and most accurate. Can I do this somehow, even though s/he didn't create a new answer, but commented on my OP?

Comment: You could write your own answer (complete one please), and refer you got your problem solved from that comment. Also you could ping the commenter in another comment and ask them for writing it down in an answer.

Comment: Somewhat ironic that you answered this question in a comment on the OP, so I can't mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I would like to mark the original commenter as the correct answer because s/he was the first and most accurate.

Well, you can only accept answers. Comments are second class citizens and not meant to give answers.

Your choices are

1. Accept the most correct from the given answers
2. Write your own answer (a complete one please), and refer you got your problem solved from that comment.
3. Ping the commenter in another comment and ask them for writing it down in an answer.
4. Leave everything as is.